# I would like to know about BigQuery output destination tables

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

BigQuery scheduled queries and I would like to know one point when spitting out the output of a select statement into a separate table.
I am new to Google Cloud Platform.

The last table that outputs using order by will not have the Is the result of the output spit out as it is?
I would like to write to the table of output results of the schedule query after sorting by order by id. Is that possible?

Sorry for the rudimentary question, but thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you share what you have, what you expect and what you did?

Comment: We apologize.We are unable to share.

For example, but suppose you have the following data.
id category
1 A
3 C
2 B

At this time, when "order by id ASC" is used in the last sql statement of the schedule query, the
I want the output destination table to contain the following
id category
1 A
2 B
3 C

In the schedule query, if I output the output with orderby at the end, will the tables in the result also be inserted with the order by applied?

Comment: Yes, it should. The scheduled query run a standard query and store the result in a target table. No difference, and the statement are executed similarly!

Answer (score 0):

BigQuery tables don't guarantee a certain order of its records. Unless you're using [clustering](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/clustered-tables) - this will physically sort the data in the background. But this will also not guarantee a sorted output of a query. You have to use `ORDER BY` in order to have a sorted output guaranteed. That means you need a key by which you can sort.